# Extract character from string based on character in another vector in R

Tags: r, string

I'm totally new to the community and hope my question and example meet the criteria.

I've got a dataframe with two character vectors. The values in vector a vary in length, the values in vector b all consist of exactly one character.

```
a <- as.character(c("tsm", "skr", "fl", "pfl", "ts", "St", "S"))
b <- as.character(c("m", "k", "l", "l", "s", "t", "S"))
uedf <- data.frame(a, b)
```

I want to extract the character in a directly to the left of a character that is specified in vector b. The position of that character within the string can vary. So, from the first string, I want to extract "s" (left of m), in the second again "s" (left of k) and so on.

As I couldn't figure out how to do this using `grepl()` (I'm not very familiar with regex), I finally ended up with a combination of `strsplit()` and `str_sub()`.

```
str_sub(strsplit(uedf$a,split=uedf$b, fixed=FALSE), start = -1, end = -1)
```

This works well for most cases except the second where it returns ")" instead of the desired "s".

```
[1] "s" ")" "f" "f" "t" "S" ""
```

Any ideas why this might be and how I could solve the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `str_sub` only works with strings but for the second string `strsplit` gives you a vector of 2 strings.

This would do the job in the case the separator only appears once in every string:

```
sapply(strsplit(a,split=b, fixed=FALSE), function(l) str_sub(l[[1]],-1,-1))
```

Comment: Ah, so that's why I had trouble with the second string. Thank you! But your solution seems to return all characters before the one specified by b, not just the one adjacent to it.

Comment: I corrected it so that it returns only the last character from the string followed by the separator

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using base R's `gsub`:

```
sapply(1:length(a), function(i) ifelse(
    nchar(a[i]) > 1,
    gsub(paste0("^.*(\\w)", b[i], ".*$"), "\\1", a[i]),
    ""))
#[1] "s" "s" "f" "f" "t" "S" ""
```

Or even more concise and cleaner/neater using `mapply` (thanks to @thelatemail):

```
mapply(function(a,b) ifelse(
    nchar(a) > 1, 
    gsub(paste0("^.*(\\w)", b, ".*$"), "\\1", a), 
    ""), a, b)
```

Comment: That does the trick, thank you very much! Just for clarification: Is "\\1" the part that tells R to return just one character?

Comment: @sakwa Generally `"\\1"` returns the expression captured in group 1. In this case, this is `(\\w)`,  and corresponds to one character.

Comment: @MauritsEvers - go for it.

Comment: @MauritsEvers: Thanks for the explanation! And the `mapply` solution (also @thelatemail)!

Answer (score 2):

Here I locate positions that match your index and save them in `i`. Then extract the characters one less then `i`.

```
i <- mapply(regexpr, b, a) - 1
substr(a, i, i)
[1] "s" "s" "f" "f" "t" "S" ""
```

Comment: A similar logic would be to `strsplit` and `match`, then `substr`ing the same way: `n <- mapply(match, b, strsplit(a,"")) - 1; substr(a, n, n)` . Likewise you could also re-write your `sapply` line as `mapply(regexpr, b, a)`

Comment: Very interesting solution(s)! Thank you very much!

Comment: @thelatemail Nice! I often forget to utilize the power of mapply.